# Program crashing with "D/ADB_SERVICES: closing because is_eof=1" on insertData

Tags: java, android, database, android-sqlite

My program is crashing on `insertData`, and I don't know how to determine the cause of this error (I'm junior in Android DataBase development and I've never used it before).

I think my insert method is not properly handling inserting values like boolean or int. Could someone point out the cause of this error?

### LogCat

> 06-02 12:28:04.439 8601-8601/? D/ADB_SERVICES: closing because is_eof=1 r=-1 s->fde.force_eof=0

### My DataBase.java

```
public class DataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DataOfSchedule.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "DataOfSchedule_table";
    public static final String COL_ID = "ID";
    public static final String COL_NAME = "NAME";
    public static final String COL_AGE = "AGE";
    public static final String COL_GENDER_M = "GENDER_M";
    public static final String COL_GENDER_F = "GENDER_F";
    public static final String COL_WEIGHT = "WEIGHT";
    public static final String COL_HEIGHT = "HEIGHT";
    public static final String COL_TRAUMA = "TRAUMA";

    public DataBase(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME +
                COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COL_NAME + " TEXT," +
                COL_AGE + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, " +
                COL_GENDER_M + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, " +
                COL_GENDER_F + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, " +
                COL_TRAUMA + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, " +
                COL_WEIGHT + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, " +
                COL_HEIGHT + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
    }

    //  public boolean insertData(String name, Integer age, Integer sex_male, Integer sex_female, Integer weight, Integer height, Integer trauma){
    //    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    //    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        public boolean insertData(String name, int age, int gender_m, int gender_f, int weight, int height, int trauma){
            boolean success = false;
            try{
                SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put(COL_NAME, name);
                contentValues.put(COL_AGE, age);
                contentValues.put(COL_GENDER_M, gender_m);
                contentValues.put(COL_GENDER_F, gender_f);
                contentValues.put(COL_WEIGHT, weight);
                contentValues.put(COL_HEIGHT, height);
                contentValues.put(COL_TRAUMA, trauma);
                long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
                db.close();

                if(result != -1) success = true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex){

            }

            return success;
        }

    public Cursor getALLData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("Select * from "+ TABLE_NAME,null);
        return res;
    }
}
```

### My InsertData.java

```
public class InsertData extends AppCompatActivity {
    DataBase myDb;
    EditText txtName, txtAge , txtWeight, txtHeight;
    CheckBox boxGender_m,boxGender_f,boxTrauma;
    Button btnClick;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_insert_data);
        myDb = new DataBase(this);
        txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        txtAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);
        boxGender_m = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.gender_m);
        boxGender_f = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.gender_f);
        boxTrauma = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.trauma);
        txtWeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight);
        txtHeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.height);
        btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.InsertBtn);
        btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                ClickMe();
            }
        });
    }

    private void ClickMe(){
        String name = txtName.getText().toString();
        String age = txtAge.getText().toString();
       // String gender_m = boxGender_m.getText().toString(); Wrong
       // String gender_f = boxGender_f.getText().toString(); Wrong
        // String trauma = boxTrauma.getText().toString();
        String weight = txtName.getText().toString();
        String height = txtName.getText().toString();
        int gender_int_m = 0;
        if (boxGender_m.isChecked()) {
            gender_int_m = 1;
        }
        int gender_int_f = 0;
        if (boxGender_f.isChecked()) {
            gender_int_f = 1;
        }
        int trauma_int = 0;
        if (boxTrauma.isChecked()) {
            gender_int_f = 1;
        }
      // int gender_int_m = Integer.parseInt(gender_m);
       // int gender_int_f = Integer.parseInt(gender_f);
       // int trauma_int = Integer.parseInt(trauma);
        int weight_int = Integer.parseInt(weight);
        int age_int = Integer.parseInt(age);
        int height_int = Integer.parseInt(height);
        Boolean result = myDb.insertData (name, age_int, gender_int_m, gender_int_f, weight_int, height_int, trauma_int);
        if (result == true){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Data Inserted Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Data Inserted Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Intent i = new Intent(this,ResultData.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

### InsertData - layout.html

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context="daniel_nikulshyn_and_andrew_rybka.myway.InsertData">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/heading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/insert_heading"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="#021aee"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/insert_name"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/age"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/insert_age"
        android:numeric="integer"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/weight"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/insert_weight"
        android:numeric="integer"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/height"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/insert_height"
        android:numeric="integer"/>

    <TextView
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/insert_gender"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/gender_m"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/male"/>
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/gender_f"
        android:text="@string/female"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/insert_trauma"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/trauma"
        android:text="@string/insert_trauma_subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/InsertBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="@string/insert_button"
        android:textColor="#f2fde4"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: please show your logcat

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: My LogCat - 06-02 12:28:04.439 8601-8601/? D/ADB_SERVICES:  closing because is_eof=1 r=-1 s->fde.force_eof=0

Comment: Thanks for information

Comment: I highly doubt that your logcat contains **1 line only**. When we ask for the logcat, we want the **full, unedited one**

Comment: because is_eof=1 r=-1 s->fde.force_eof=0
06-02 W/ADB_SERVICES: entered. LS(4075) fd=25
06-02  W/ADB_SERVICES: create_local_service_socket() name=shell:cat /proc/14983/stat
06-02  W/ADB_SERVICES: service_to_fd() name=shell:cat /proc/14983/stat
06-02  W/ADB_SERVICES: read_meminfo() mem_free=9492
06-02 W/ADB_SERVICES: create_subprocess() ret_fd=25 pid=16986
06-02 W/ADB_SERVICES: LS(4076): bound to 'shell:cat /proc/14983/stat' via 25
06-02  W/ADB_SERVICES: adb: unable to open /proc/16986/oom_adj
06-02  D/ADB_SERVICES:  closing

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a number of issues. However, `D/ADB_SERVICES: closing because is_eof=1 r=-1 s->fde.force_eof=0` doesn't appear to be one of them. The D/ indicates that it is DEBUG message and shouldn't be a show stopper *(This appears to be a device (android implementation) dependant message some may get this message other may not)*.

#### Number Format Exception

Before the database and table gets created (assuming only the above activity) then the insert could fail (if the name input is not numeric) as you are trying to parse the **name** as an int for the **weight** and the **height**.

You would have an exception along the lines of the following :-

```
06-03 00:08:31.518 2745-2745/va.vehicleapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "Fred"
        at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
        at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
        at va.vehicleapp.MainActivity.ClickMe(MainActivity.java:172)
        at va.vehicleapp.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:16)
        at va.vehicleapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:44)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

As such you should change to use the following lines within the `onClick` method :-

```
    String weight = txtWeight.getText().toString(); // CHANGED to txtWeight not txtName
    String height = txtHeight.getText().toString(); // CHANGED to txtHeight not txtName
```

#### The Table will not be created

I suspect that if you look at the log you will see (or would have seen at some time, if you even got as far as invoking the onCreate method) something along the lines of :-

```
06-02 23:24:12.135 2113-2113/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "TABLEDataOfSchedule_tableID": syntax error
06-02 23:24:12.135 2113-2113/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-02 23:24:12.135 2113-2113/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6244288)
06-02 23:24:12.135 2113-2113/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{va.vehicleapp/va.vehicleapp.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEDataOfSchedule_tableID": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEDataOfSchedule_tableID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT,AGE INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, GENDER_M INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, GENDER_F INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, TRAUMA INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, WEIGHT INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, HEIGHT INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEDataOfSchedule_tableID": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEDataOfSchedule_tableID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT,AGE INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, GENDER_M INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, GENDER_F INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, TRAUMA INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, WEIGHT INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, HEIGHT INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1663)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
        at va.vehicleapp.DataBase.onCreate(DataBase.java:27)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
        at va.vehicleapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is because in your **DataBase** class you have a few omissions, spaces and an opening parenthesis, that will result in the table not being created.

The fix for these is to

1. change the `onCreate` method to (see comments for changes made)

:-

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + //<<<< ADDED space
            " (" +  // ADDED to enclose column definition in brackets
            COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COL_NAME + " TEXT," +
            COL_AGE + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, " +
            COL_GENDER_M + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, " +
            COL_GENDER_F + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, " +
            COL_TRAUMA + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, " +
            COL_WEIGHT + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, " +
            COL_HEIGHT + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);");
}
```

2. either, delete the App's Data, uninstall the App or increase the Database version to 2 i.e. (change `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,1);` to `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,2);`
3. and then Rerun the App.

#### Testing Result

Making the above changes, running *(after deleting the App's Data important to do to create the correct table)*, completing the input fields using :-

- Fred,
- 10,
- 21,
- 45,
- male (ticked),
- female (ticked),

  - able to tick both????
    -insert_trauma_subtitle not ticked

resulted in Toast confirming insertion.